# jQuery Chosen: display multiple select fields on the same page

Tags: jquery, html, laravel, jquery-chosen

I am using https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ to allow user to search for values in a dropdown list.

I also have 2 tabs on the `post/create` page: Link & Text

Both tabs have the same "subreddit_id" field that is using `$(selector).chosen();` however, jquery chosen only displays on the first tab but not the second. If I remove the class name from the second tab, a normal dropdown will appear populated by my data, if I add the class `chosen-select`, the fields doesn't load at all.

I am using the same field on both tabs.

[image]

Not sure why this is happening. I have tried using the example code supplied with the plugin but it didn't work either

```
for (var selector in config) {
      $(selector).chosen(config[selector]);
    }
```

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.chosen-select').chosen();
       $('.chosen-select1').chosen();
   });
</script>

<div class="bs-posts bs-posts-tabs" data-posts-id="togglable-tabs">
        <ul id="myTabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" id="home-tab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-expanded="true">Link</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" role="tab" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="profile">Text</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home" aria-labelledBy="home-tab">

                {!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'title']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('link', 'Link:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('link', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'link']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('subreddit', 'Subreddit:') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('subreddit_id', $subreddits, null, ['class' => 'chosen-select']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::submit('Submit Post', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </p>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" aria-labelledBy="profile-tab">
                {!! Form::open(['url' => 'posts', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('title', 'Title:') !!}
                    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'title']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('text', 'Text:') !!}
                    {!! Form::textarea('text', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'text']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::label('subreddit', 'Subreddit:') !!}
                    {!! Form::select('subreddit_id', $subreddits, null, ['class' => 'chosen-select1']) !!}
                </p>

                <p>
                    {!! Form::submit('Submit Post', ['id' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                </p>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /tabs -->
```

Comment: did u try with `id`s instead of `class`?

Comment: can you create a sample plunker of ur case?

Comment: I don't use laravel, is the html populated in the DOM ready? Or when the tab is opened?

Comment: ah may be you can try triggering the chosen on second tab select when click on the second tab.

Comment: Yes, the html is ready before I click on the second tab, just checked with firebug. This is the plunk you asked for, but clicking on the second tab doesn't work for some reason even though everything is in place. http://embed.plnkr.co/V57x6YkUOZW0McLpM6BJ/preview

Comment: @K.Toress I tried what you suggested and it kinda worked. However, the `jquery chosen` field only appears when I click inside the page of the second tab, until then it looks like a normal dropdown field. I used this `$('#profile').click(function() {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to trigger the plugin in the tab change you can use the event `shown.bs.tab` event.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
        debugger
        if (target == '#home') {
            $('.chosen-select').chosen();
        }
        if (target == '#profile') {
            $('.chosen-select1').chosen();
        }
    });

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]:first').trigger("shown.bs.tab");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/o9xp6zcd/

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.chosen-select').chosen();
  $('.chosen-select1').chosen({width: "100%"});
});
```